# I get an error when I try to show the comments for each post

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error:

ErrorException in Connection.php line 647: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'comments.dummy_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `comments` where `comments`.`dummy_id` = 1 and `comments`.`dummy_id` is not null) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\app\resources\views\post.blade.php)

I have two tables one called dummies and the other called comments. I know it should have been called post instead of dummies my bad. I made a foreign key on the comments table to link to the field called id in the dummies table.

Here is the dummies migration file which should have been called post:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDummiesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('dummies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('dummies');
    }
}
```

here is the comments migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCommentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('post_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('dummies');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('comments');
    }
}
```

let me know if you guys need the users or any other migration files. I only showed those two because i believe that is where the problem is. I am just so confused to why it's giving me an error on a field that doesn't even exist which is the dummy_id field.

Here is my post.blade.php file that MattClark requested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
      @yield('css')
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>

  <body>
      @include('layout.nav')

      <main>
        <h3> {{ $post->name }}</h3>
        <p>{{ $post->created_at->toDayDateTimeString() }}</p>
        <p> {{ $post->body }}</p>
      </main>
      <ul>
        @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
        <li>{{ $comment->body }}</li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
       @include('layout.footer')
    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      @yield('javascript')
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like you should be using `comments.post_id` instead of `comments.dummy_id` in `post.blade.php`

Comment: @MattClark I don't use comments.post_id or comments.dummy_id in post.blade.php. What do you mean by this? I'll show you my post.blade.php file on the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default laravel assumes your foreign key is `dummy_id`. Change this in your Dummy or Post model, whatever you've named it.

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'post_id');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my first time using stack overflow and this made my life so much easier to learn. Thank you so so so much. :)

Comment: @Lami No problem. Glad to help.